# Curvature gradient from second fundamental form coeffiecients

Tags: differential-geometry

I have Monge patch surface given as $h=h(u,v)$ and analyze it in points of interest using the usual formulas for coefficients of the first and the second fundamental forms:
\begin{align}
   E&=1+h_u^2, & e&=\frac{h_{uu}}{(1+h_u^2+h_v^2)^{1/2}}, \\
   F&=h_u h_v, & f&=\frac{h_{uv}}{(1+h_u^2+h_v^2)^{1/2}}, \\
   F&=1+h_v^2, & g&=\frac{h_{vv}}{(1+h_u^2+h_v^2)^{1/2}}. \\
\end{align}
The values of $h_u$, $h_v$, $h_{uu}$, $h_{uv}$, $h_{vv}$ are known numerically from polynomial approximation of point cloud.

I understand principal curvatures $\kappa_i$ are eigenvalues of $$\begin{pmatrix}E & F \\ F & G\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}e&f\\ f&g\end{pmatrix}=\mathbf{I}^{-1}\mathbf{II}.$$

I need to compute gradient of the major principal curvature $\kappa_2$ (more specifically its slope perpendicular to its direction, i.e. in the first principal direction  $e_1$).

I tried to express the gradient analytically from the eigenvalue problem but got lost in the expressions. Was I on the right track?

I am not an expert in differential geometry & might be missing something obvious; I hope at least I got the question stated correctly :)

Comment: You're missing the *first* fundamental form. The principal curvatures/directions are eigenvalues/eigenvectors of the matrix $\text{I}^{-1}\text{II}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I understood a bit more from your *Differential Geometry: A First Course in Curves and Surfaces* (thanks :) ) and re-phrased the problem, hopefully it makes more sense now.